# Can images in NSAttributesString(generated from HTML) of UILabel/UITextView be loaded asynchronously(iOS 7+)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, nsattributedstring

Recently I'm trying to implement a rich text view for displaying contents such as a topic content or a reply(including some images usually). I tried DTCoreText in UITableView but there seemed to be many problems.

I just found that since iOS 7, UITextView/UILabel began to support NSAttributedText, but the problems is that all the images are loaded synchronously, they will block the main thread. Is there any way to make it possible to load them asynchronously?

Sample code:
https://gist.github.com/romaonthego/6672863

Answer (score 1):

```
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```

In this line you should download data before set it to attributed string.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
    // Load Data Here.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Create NSAttributedString and set data to it.
    });
});
```